# google.cloud translate doesn't work in Docker (Python)

Tags: docker, google-translate

### **SOLUTION**

I needed to add `RUN apk add gcc g++ musl-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev` to Dockerfile. Now it works. Just building time increased.

### Original Question

I'm new to docker.

I've a class where I run google translate API. It runs on local.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6.6-alpine3.8

# Project files
ARG PROJECT_DIR=/srv/api
RUN mkdir -p $PROJECT_DIR
WORKDIR $PROJECT_DIR

RUN apk add gcc musl-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev

# Install Python dependencies
COPY ./ ./
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install google-cloud-translate
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

It crashes when I `docker-compose build`

```
 ERROR: Complete output from command /usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-9k79v_vp/grpcio/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-3w3baynf --python-tag cp36:
  ERROR: Found cython-generated files...
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  running build_project_metadata
  creating python_build
  creating python_build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
  creating python_build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/grpc
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/_server.py -> python_build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/grpc
<..>
ERROR: Command "/usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-9k79v_vp/grpcio/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-vb12kr37/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-9k79v_vp/grpcio/
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide your entire `dockerfile`

Comment: Thanks! Updated!

Comment: Solution was to add this to Dockerfile
```RUN apk add gcc g++ musl-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev```

Besides long build time - it works!

Answer (score 1):

```
  gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
```

You need to install `g++` as well.